# Web Browser to create socket connection to the local machine.

Tags: linux, html, web-services, web

I am very new to Web technology. Sorry if the question is very basic.

1) There is a website called xyz.com.

2) Assume my system is having a daemon process which can interact with socket.

3) When i click on xyz.com, i need to interact with the local machine socket provided by daemon process.

ie: communication between the web browser, and local machine, without server interaction.

**QUESTIONS:**

Is it possible ? if so, kindly suggest which tools that i can use?

HTML5?

Answer (score 0):

[You should check this article out first.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebSockets) HTML5 spec include a websocket API that allows you to do just that. But before any client usage, you need a server implementation first. NodeJS already have a SocketIO, and a PEAR package has been made available. Please check your server side availability before any implementation.

Angela